# how to write a bat file to execute the .sql file

Tags: mysql

I want to execute a query inside a db.sql file using MySQL 5.1 in the Windows environment. Can any one help me with this? I want to do this by running a .bat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Col Shrapnel's answer is the way to do it. The batch file would look like this:

```
mysql < %1
```

...which really just shows that it'd just be easier to use that directly instead of a .bat.

```
runsql myfile.sql  // (assuming you name your batch file "runsql.bat")
// vs
mysql < myfile.sql
```

---

Reading your comment on the other answer, it seems like you might actually get some use out of the batch file as long as you don't mind storing your password in plain text on your computer.

Make the batch file like this:

```
mysql -u myusername -pmypassword < %1
```

Note that there is no space between `-p` and `mypassword`. If you use that above, every script would have to specify which database to use, which might be a hassle. The other way you could do it is like this:

```
mysql -u myusername -pmypassword -D %1 < %2
```

And the usage would be:

```
mysql database_name input.sql
```

Comment: mysql -u root -proot test < db.sql

this worked for me. but the problem is i have to run the bat file inside the mysql bin folder. I want to run it from the desktop. How can I specify the path

Comment: a) add the mysql bin folder to the system path. -OR- b) type the full path into the batch file (`c:\mysql\bin\mysql -u ....`)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql.exe < db.sql
```

Comment: it gives a error'access denied with password no' how can i give the username and password

Comment: @ganuke by typing `mysql --help` you can get help on using mysql console