# Windows Task schedule MySQL query because LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, windows, task, scheduler

I just want to execute a command that reads a CSV file and store it into MySQL Db every day.

when i run this command it works fine "load data local infile 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.csv' into table cdr.test fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';"

Then i tried to create a MySQL scheduler event "CREATE EVENT newEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Day
DO
load data local infile '/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.csv' into table cdr.test fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
;". However it says LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedure.

there is a way to use Windows Task scheduler (bat file) to run MySQL query but i was not successful in doing it!!!!

Please help.

Comment: Ok finally it is working yaaaa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927324/how-to-write-a-bat-file-to-execute-the-sql-file

Comment: @user2389290 How did you get this to work? #necromancer